# AV playback synchronization using ffmpeg on WPF

Tags: wpf, ffmpeg, h.264

I have Video( H264-1080p-30fps) and Audio (Mu-law-8k) in separate files both are generated from same camera source. My work is to play them both synchronously using ffmpeg. I can able to decode video and audio without any issue but I don't know how to play AV synchronously on WPF.

1. What is the best way to render the video and play audio on Wpf after decoding?
2. How to play them synchronously?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the video and audio as follows:

1) Copying audio directly without re-encoding

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i myaudio.wav -c copy myoutput.mkv
```

2) With audio re-encoding

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i myaudio.wav -c:v copy \
-c:a aac -strict experimental myoutput.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but i'm looking av synchronization in programmatically. Can you help me with right direction to start ?